# Can Access be accessed via PHP PDO and fast?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, dynamics-crm

I have a database in Access I need to access a Microsoft Access database via the internet and am building a PHP interface. I would like to know if it would be better to convert to MySQL or Microsoft CRM Dynamics as would they be faster?

My other question is can MS Access or MS Dynamics even be accessed via PHP PDO currently? If not my first questions is redundant and MySQL is the way to go.

Regards,
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

it certainly makes sense to migrate your data into a normal relational database system, regardless if that is MariaDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL or whatever. Many advantages exist besides performance, for example you get rid of the vendor lock in and have free access to your data the way you want to. This includes using php to access that data. Is there any reason *against* migrating it? I mean reasons expect "we always used MS-Access" or the like...

And I never heard of a reliable and stable MS-Access driver for PHP.